# C++ std::stoi Exception: Invalid Argument

Tags: c++, exception

I am writing a program which calculates the avarage color hex code from two color hex codes.
For example: We have an input to the console of two hex codes #15293E and #012549.

Then it calculates the avarage hex code - #0B2743

So, my main problem is when i convert from string to int with the function std::stoi
It gives me an exception for invalid argument.
Here is the code i've written so far

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define CONSOLE_LOG(x) std::cout << x
#define HEX_LEN 6
#define RGB_LEN 2

void enterHexCodes(std::string& hC1, std::string& hC2)
{
    bool isCorrectLen = false;
    do {
        std::cin >> hC1 >> hC2;
        if (hC1.length() != HEX_LEN + 1 || hC2.length() != HEX_LEN + 1)
        { 
            CONSOLE_LOG("ERROR!: Hex code should be no more than 7 symbols" << std::endl);
        } else { isCorrectLen = true; }
    } while (!isCorrectLen);
}

void getAvgHex(std::string& s, std::string& s1)
{
    int r, g, b,
        r1, g1, b1;

    std::string R = s.substr(1, RGB_LEN);
    std::string G = s.substr(3, RGB_LEN);
    std::string B = s.substr(5, RGB_LEN);

    std::string R1 = s1.substr(1, RGB_LEN);
    std::string G1 = s1.substr(3, RGB_LEN);
    std::string B1 = s1.substr(5, RGB_LEN);

    try {
        r = std::stoi(R), g = std::stoi(G), b = std::stoi(B);
        //std::stoi(R1), std::stoi(G1), std::stoi(B1);
    }
    catch (std::invalid_argument& e) {
        std::cout << "Invalid argument" << std::endl;
    }
    catch (std::out_of_range& e) {
        std::cout << "Out of range" << std::endl;
    }
    catch (...) {
        std::cout << "Something else" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << r << " " << g << " " << b;

}

int main()
{
    std::string hexCode1, hexCode2;

    enterHexCodes(hexCode1, hexCode2);

    getAvgHex(hexCode1, hexCode2);

    std::cin.get(); std::cin.get(); std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

How can i fix this exception, or is there any other way i can convert a string to an int?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try adding the base of conversion 
example for hex : std::stoi (str_hex,nullptr,16);

Comment: It worked, thank you very much.
Could you explain me why it worked and why my method didn't work?

Comment: Welcome. If you don't  pass the base then the function expect a string of decimal digit

Comment: If you don't specify a base, the first few characters in the input determine the base. If the text starts with a non-0 digit, it's base 10. If it starts with a 0 followed by an x or an X it's hexadecimal. If it starts with 0 followed by something other than an x or an X it's octal. So "15293E" is interpreted as a decimal constant, and the `E` at the end isn't valid. "012549" is an octal constant, and the `9` at the end isn't valid.